# How to display object based on what user clicked?

Tags: navigation, hyperlink

For a single post that I have links on, is there a way to know if the user has clicked any of the links?  The links don't go anywhere.  They just open a popup. I'd like to display a check mark next to each link the user has clicked.  This allows the user to know if they have already visited those links.

If that is not possible, is there a way to capture the last link a user has clicked?  At least that way, the user can tell where they stopped when they come back to the page.

If none of the above is possible, will coloring these unvisited links something that stands out and then coloring visited links something that fades into the page (light gray visited link on white page) work?  That will probably reset once cookies or browser history is deleted.  But it would be better than nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can just use the `:visited` selector to style it how you'd like. So something like this would give all visited links a grey color and put them in italic:

```
a:visited {
   color: #ddd;
   font-style: italic;
}
```

You would add this to your stylesheet.

[**Read more on the `:visited` selector here.**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_visited.asp)